# cakephp using paginate and order

Tags: cakephp

HI,
why not work "order" function?

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'limit' => 5,
                'order' => array(
                    'User.name' => 'desc'
                ),
                'fields' => array('Post.id', 'Post.title', 'User.name AS aut_name'),                        
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' =>'users',
                        'alias' =>'User',
                        'type' =>'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'Post.user_id = User.user_id'
                        )
                    )
                )
        );  

        $posts = $this->paginate();
        $this->set(compact('posts'));
```

DB structure:

```
posts:
id, title,body, created, updated, user_id

users:
user_id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking quickly your code... Does field user_id exist in User table?

```
'conditions' => array(
    'Post.user_id = User.id'
)
```

Comment: in this conditions i connect post with author. I get all date correctly, but data no sorted by condition.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're specifying `User.name As aut_name` in your `fields`, you won't be able to order by `User.name` unless you also have `User.name` in your `fields` list. Alternatively use:

```
'order' => array(
    'aut_name' => 'desc'
),
```

NOTE: This is for the initial query only, to sort by aut_name from the View you'll need to use a Virtual Field in the User model.

Also, as @Min said, are your conditions correct?

Comment: "unless you also have User.name in your fields list" - which list? I chage to "'aut_name' => 'desc'" and add <?php echo $paginator->sort('Author', 'aut_name'); ?> but sort no work. Why? Thanks

Comment: Using $paginator->sort in the view is a totally different problem, if you're needing to do that, then you need to use a virtual field that gives you the aut_name in every query of User.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a solution on the same problem:

This work for cakePHP 2.3.4

[CakePHP Paginate conditions on Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645296/cakephp-paginate-conditions-on-join-table/16789816#16789816)